# Why is the installation of gef on my windows giving me this error?

Tags: python, gdb, reverse-engineering

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "c:\msys64\mingw64\share\gdb/python\gdb\__init__.py", line 130, in _execute_file
exec(compiled, globals, globals)
File "C:\Users\AZ\gef\gef.py", line 11583, in <module>
PYTHONBIN = which("python3")
File "C:\Users\AZ\gef\gef.py", line 1738, in which
raise FileNotFoundError(f"Missing file `{program}`")
FileNotFoundError: Missing file `python3`
```

I cannot find solution to this error on google that's why I decided to ask here.

Comment: [Here](https://gef.readthedocs.io/en/master/#bugs-feedbacks) it says: `GEF fully relies on the GDB API and other Linux-specific sources of information (such as /proc/<pid>)` So it can't work on Windows.

Comment: but i read somewhere that it was os agnostic.

Comment: Than that `somewhere` seems to be wrong.

Comment: [Here](https://gef.readthedocs.io/en/master/) it does claim that gef is OS Agnostic.  The error appears to indicate that python3 was not found in your $PATH.  Make sure you have python3 install, then follow [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537574(v=office.14)) to add the location of python3 to your PATH.

Comment: but python 3 is installed in my path when I run the python command it shows me the version of the python I have installed and it is python3.

Comment: "When I run the `python` command" - yes but does it work when you run _the `python3` command_?

Comment: yes it does, everything is working fine but GEF cannot seem to work can anyone else try this and share their experience if they run into the same issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.